# Interpolation function for data with repeating independent variable

Tags: interpolation, dataset, data-structures

I want to find an interpolation function for data in which the x-variable is repeated (example below). The repetition in data is natural and cannot not be eliminated.

Can I somehow use `Interpolation` or is there any alternative?

```
tb = {{1, 1.83014}, {2, 8.58075}, {3, 7.51278}, {4, 6.12041}, {5, 
    2.35631}, {6, 9.5376}, {7, 6.58829}, {8, 3.11074}, {9, 
    9.39695}, {10, 8.3102}, {1, 6.51489}, {2, 3.94981}, {3, 
    8.27251}, {4, 7.03619}, {5, 4.06204}, {6, 0.662478}, {7, 
    7.5016}, {8, 7.84269}, {9, 5.64659}, {10, 7.54041}, {1, 
    6.51489}, {2, 3.94981}, {3, 8.27251}, {4, 7.03619}, {5, 
    4.06204}, {6, 0.662478}, {7, 7.5016}, {8, 7.84269}, {9, 
    5.64659}, {10, 7.54041}};

Interpolation[tb, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
(* Interpolation: The point 1 in dimension 1 is duplicated *)
```

Comment: Which value should `Interpolation[tb,...][1]` return, `1.83014` or `6.51489`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
par = Interpolation /@ Partition[tb, 10];

ListLinePlot[par]
```

[image]

```
par[[1]][1.5]
```

6.65115

```
par[[1]][Range @ 9 + 0.5] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

It should be noted that the middle partition and the last partition are identical:

```
tb[[11 ;; 20]] == tb[[21 ;; 30]]
```

True

Answer (score 2):

If it makes sense for your objective to identify the first 10 values as category 0 and the second 10 as category 1, then the following might be considered:

```
tb = {{1, 1.83014}, {2, 8.58075}, {3, 7.51278}, {4, 6.12041}, {5, 2.35631}, 
      {6, 9.5376}, {7, 6.58829}, {8, 3.11074}, {9, 9.39695}, {10, 8.3102},
      {1, 6.51489}, {2, 3.94981}, {3, 8.27251}, {4, 7.03619}, {5, 4.06204}, 
      {6, 0.662478}, {7, 7.5016}, {8, 7.84269}, {9, 5.64659}, {10, 7.54041}};
data = Flatten[#] & /@ Transpose[{Join[ConstantArray[0, 10], ConstantArray[1, 10]], tb}]

f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

f[1, 1]
(* 6.51489 *)
f[0,10]
(* 8.3102 *)
```